# I built a PC with a hard drive from an old system, and now my TP Link Archer T4U USB isn't working properly

Tags: networking, drivers, usb

I have tried every single thing to get it to work.

- Reinstalled Drivers
- Used both Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and 16.04 (I have both on the same drive)
- Tried using a completely different USB Stick

But nothing works!
I'm getting tired of using my phone as an ethernet cord.
Can anyone please help?

Terminal Results:

Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04b4:f02f Cypress Semiconductor Corp.

Bus 001 Device 007: ID 05ac:12a8 Apple, Inc. iPhone5/5C/5S/6

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` Which driver suite did you reinstall? Welcome to Ask Ubtuntu.